# Postman: How can I set my postman to use "pm" instead of "postman"

Tags: postman

I'm trying to learn my way around Postman and I see in Tests, for example `pm.globals.set("id","12345")` is used instead of `postman.setGlobalVariable("id","12345")` which is what I have working on mine. The former does not. I want to be able to use `pm.globals.set`

Comment: Which version of Postman are you using? ```pm.*``` is a relatively new API. See [postman vs pm](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3648)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new `pm.*` API was introduced in version 5.2.0 - https://www.getpostman.com/apps#changelog

Looking at the release notes for that version, the native OS clients have been updated but the Chrome App doesn't show this change. I believe the development for the Chrome App has now stopped.

The older syntax will still continue to work in the new versions but it will be dropped eventually in favour of the new `pm.*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

The postman has replaced Postman.* to pm.* which has more cleaner and robust scripting. It includes a lot of global functions. This link explains the same : https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/

This should help you understand the additional features in it.